# SVG motion path flipping issue

Tags: animation, svg

I am trying to animate a train across a angled line. I have generated the SVG page and the train animates accordingly. However when the train gets the the end of the line, its flips and goes backwards.

[DEMO HERE](https://codepen.io/danyo-borg/pen/JZLVgz)

```
.largetrainpath{
    position: absolute;
    left: 37%;
    top: 670px;
    z-index: 99999999;
}


.largeTrain{
    motion-path: path("M1,3C64.3,24.3,127,47.5,189.8,70.1c1.8,0.7,2.6-2.2,0.8-2.9C127.8,44.6,65.1,21.4,1.8,0.1          C0-0.5-0.8,2.4,1,3L1,3z");
    offset-path: path("M1,3C64.3,24.3,127,47.5,189.8,70.1c1.8,0.7,2.6-2.2,0.8-2.9C127.8,44.6,65.1,21.4,1.8,0.1          C0-0.5-0.8,2.4,1,3L1,3z");
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
    motion-rotation: reverse;
    animation: move 3s linear;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    width: 94px;
    height: 43px;
    background: url(img/large-train.png) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
    top: 654px;
    z-index: 99999999999;
}

@keyframes move {
100% { 
    motion-offset: 100%;
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
```

Any ideas how i can prevent the train from flipping, and going back on itself? Once it gets to the end of the line i would like the animation to stop there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because your path is not a single line from the start to the end.  It is a long thin rectangle instead.  The path goes from the start to the end, turns the corner, then goes back to the start.

To fix this, trim the path down to just the bit up until the bottom right "end" point.  For example:

```
.largeTrain {
    motion-path: path("M1,3C64.3,24.3,127,47.5,189.8,70.1");
    offset-path: path("M1,3C64.3,24.3,127,47.5,189.8,70.1");
 }
```